# django.db.utils.OperationalError: while deploying to pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: How does your db configuration in django settings looks like?

Answer (score 0):

- This error occurs when you have set your DB to some external DB like PostgreSQL, which is not running right now. Please make sure ur DB is running.